# how to update opportunity line Item to refer a new Pricebook

Tags: opportunity, data-loader, opportunity-lineitem, pricebook

We want the existing orders on old PriceBooks to be update to New PriceBook via dataloader.

Is it possible to do this without following the below steps:?

1. Delete line items
2. update order  header with PriceBookId of new Pricebook
3. insert line items with updated PriceBookEntryId.

Answer (score 1):

The answer is 'NO'. you need to be first to "Delete" the old Opportunity Line Item and then "Insert" the new one.

The Opp Line Item records are actually a 'junction object' that hold a PriceBookEntryID and an OpportunityID.  **PriceBookEntryID  is not updatable.**

Couple of links to help you out :
https://success.salesforce.com/answers?id=90630000000hDlyAAE
https://help.salesforce.com/HTViewSolution?id=000025289&language=en_US